# Exception in expose the json array in cxf

Tags: java, web-services

I am creating a Rest api using CXF. When I am trying to expose the Rest for a single record its working fine but if I try to send a Json array then it is showing:

```
JAXBException occurred : Too many closing tags.. Too many closing tags..
```

this exception. Don't have much idea what is the problem.

Comment: can you post the actual exception, and possibly some code?

Answer (score 4):

Check the class for the objects you're sending back doesn't have a field in there with the same name as the class.  (If it does, try renaming the field ;).)